# Is it possible to get 0 count for group by queries when there are no rows for that particular group by

Tags: django, django-orm

For eg:

We have two tables

```
Note
--------------------
id | text | label_id
1  | abcs | 1
2  | accs | 2
3  | abts | 1
```

```
Label
---------
id | name
1  | pro
2  | foo
3  | bar
```

Now the data I want is

```
Label Name | Note Count
------------------------
pro        | 2
foo        | 1
bar        | 0
```

Now if I do this:
`Note.objects.all().values('label__name').annotate(count=Count('id', distinct=True))`

I wont get the 3rd row, which is (bar, 0). Is there any way to get this information? Condition being it has to be done in a single query and the query should be on Notes model and not start from the Label model

Answer (score 0):

Try like this with [conditional aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation):

```
Note.objects.annotate(
    count=Count(Case(
       When(label__note_count__gt=0, then=F('id')),
       output_field=IntegerField()
    )).all()
```